# Need idea for Two different remote MYSQL database connection in one PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

iam developing a multi tenant application. And i need an idea. as iam in a dark tunnel with no light now
there will be two database involve from two different location.

1. Database (A) - Tenant List with tenant database (B) username,password,IP address
2. Database (B) - Specific tenant info base on selected tenant from database (A)

What i want to achieve is:

1. When user enter their web url with specific user_id in url, first it will query the tenant list in Database (A) based on the user_id from url.
2. then, it will straight make a persistent connection to Database (B) using the credential from query Database (A) result.

hope to get ideas and bring me some lights. thank you!

here is what i had try:

```
 public function func_get_user($id){
    $tenant = $this->client_info_func($id); // this is function to get Tenant credential from Database A for using in database B

    if (!empty($tenant)) {
        $pdo_client = $this->cliend_db_conn($tenant['client_db_name'],$tenant['client_db_username'],$tenant['client_db_pass'],$tenant['client_db_ip']); // this is the function to initiate PDO connection to Database B
    $Q = "SELECT user_id,user_name,client_id FROM user WHERE client_id =:id";
    $R = $pdo_client->prepare($Q);
    $R->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $R->execute();
    $result = $R->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result;

    }else{
        echo 'Sorry! you are not allowed tenant';
    }


 }
```

Comment: Why 2 seperate databases and not just 2 tables in the same database?

Comment: What's difficult about that? Select the credentials from database A. Get them into PHP variables and then pass them in as parameters where PDO connects to database B.

Comment: @RiggsFolly , Database A will be in my site, while database B will be in client site.

Comment: Then as @Andy says, you can make 2 seperate connections to 2 database just use a different variable name to hold the connection i.e. `$db1` and `$db2`

Comment: Since PDO connects to only one database host IP, you can be sure you won't do this in "one" PDO.

Comment: @Andy, do you mean every time each of my database B function need to pass the credentials from Database A before execute?

Comment: See the answer below. Firstly, get the details out of database A (with a `SELECT` query). Put the row into a PHP array. Then when you make a PDO connection to database B pass in those details. They are dynamic as they have come from database A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't posted any code. But the logic is as follows:

Connect to database A using PDO as normal:

```
$pdo_db_A = new PDO(... ;dbname='database_A', 'db_A_username', 'db_A_password');
```

Then run this query on database A:

```
SELECT username, password FROM database_A_table WHERE user_id = ...
```

Get your data in PHP variables, such as an array:

```
$db['username'] = $row['username']; // $row being from the above query
$db['password'] = $row['password'];
```

Make a **separate PDO connection** to database B and pass in the details:

```
$pdo_db_B = new PDO(... ;dbname='database_B', $db['username'], $db['password']);
```

Comment: I see, so first connection to Database A i should not using PDO? the second connection using PDO?

Comment: Both use PDO. There is a connection to database A (to get the details). Then a *second* PDO connection for database B which uses those details.

Comment: No problem. I've updated the code slightly to show it's using 2 separate PDO connections...

Comment: Andy, i had updated my code, do i need to call hit database A every time i want to execute database B functions?

Comment: You need to open a connection to database A any time you want to get details (the `SELECT` query in my answer). Then you have them to pass to the connection for database B. So when the URL is opened with the user details (as you mentioned in the question) that's where you open the connection to db A, grab the details, then you're good to use them for database B.